# What's an effective way to debug uncaught syntaxerrors?

Tags: javascript, debugging, syntax-error

Recently I got stuck on uncaught syntaxerrors, and I don't have any clue on how you can effectively debug them. I'm using Chrome and I can't see what's happening when there are uncaught syntax errors, because the debugging of Chrome only seems to debug your own written code, but not the code that is being progressed, as far as my knowledge goes on debugging (which is beginnerlevel anyway).

So I got this code right here: http://jsfiddle.net/0e5ue9k7/2/

The problem is an unexpected '}' when I call

```
function userTurn(attack) {
....
}
```

at line 283, which is called by

```
function combat {
....
}
```

at line 259 after pressing a button. I know that the problem is the button onclick event, but I'm not sure what's wrong, what's going on and how I should change it, because the syntax error is uncaught. What's the best way to deal with this problem?

Any help would be very appreciated! If there's anything unclear let me know.

Comment: it's clear you got a syntax error. Check your code for missing `}`

Comment: I think the best way to avoid/find this kind of errors is coding on an IDE with a good JS parser, like IDEA WebStorm, for instance

Comment: @andrex Been there, done that...

Comment: @user3840869 Are you sure, this error is not on the function userTurn it could be somewhere else. And only show when you call some functions

Comment: Have you http://www.jshint.com/ your code?

Comment: @Pablo Thank you, I'm looking into it right now.

Comment: @epascarello That's also new for me. Well... I guess you can see how much of a beginner I am :-).

Comment: @andrex Because I've ran the code before without any problems, I was revamping most of it and then got stuck on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not find the missing "}" in your JavaScript code because the error is in your generated HTML code that your program spits out.

```
<button class="combatMoves" onclick="userTurn(" help")"="">Help</button>
```

looking at the code you have

```
<button class="combatMoves" onclick="userTurn("help")"="">Help</button>
```

when it should be

```
<button class="combatMoves" onclick="userTurn('help')"="">Help</button>
```

But since you have built the string with `'`, the `'` characters need to be escaped `\'`

Typically when the browser throws an error when you click on something and it can not find the line number, insect the element you clicked on.

Basic fix:

```
controller.innerHTML = 'Choose an attack!<br><button class="combatMoves" onclick="userTurn(\'bow\')"> ...
```

Get into the practice of not using inline event handlers.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought it was... but why is it all of a sudden onclick="userTurn(" help")"="" even though I clearly added onclick="userTurn("help")"? How does that work?

Comment: Look at what you typed. It has nothing to do with the space. The space is caused by the bug. It has to do to the quotes causing the attributes to be closed. The HTML is parsed and it sees `onclick="userTurn("` It does not magically read your mind and realize that the next couple of characters belongs with that attribute.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much for the insight. I thought it would've worked because it set it as a string, so I thought the quotation marks wouldn't matter that much inside it.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome you can debug "uncaught exceptions" by clicking on the (||) icon in the debugger. If you want to debug on caught exceptions, check the "pause on caught" option.

https://i.imgur.com/WB4GDSr.png